# Export a matrix from matlab to maple

Tags: matlab, export, maple

I have a NxN syms matrix in MATLAB and I want to export it to Maple, Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. save the matrix to a file in matlab
2. In maple, use ImportMatrix. See
       http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=ImportMatrix
       there are examples at the end of the webpage.